# Debugging android apps from a terminal suddenly not working

Tags: android, debugging, usb

I stuck in my android project since now 1 week, the usb connection from my phone(galaxy note4) to my pc (windows 7) suddenly stopped to work.
Everyday I use usb debugging to debug my projects and also try apps directly from my mobile, while few days ago when I try to connect the same mobile using the same cable as usual,  my pc not detect anything but just charge my mobile. 
I don't remember have changed something in my pc or my mobile.
here is what I ve already  tried to to solve the problem but still not working:

- I uninstalled then reinstalled the usb driver: still not working;
- I tried to connect with different data cable: same thing;
- I tried to restore my windows from one week: still not detecting my phone; 
  I tried to connect my phone to different pc windows and Ubuntu as well : weirdly not no detection happen;
- From my mobile dialing *#0808#, the mode is already in mtp+adb, I reset the same and reboot my phone: nothing changed; 
  My last hope was to wipe my mobile cache but didn't change anything so I finally wiped everything and restore to the factory state: I  regret to have done it it didn't solve my problem.

Finally I went on Google but I  just found the same things I already tried to do.
So here I come surrender to you guys, someone have any idea 
I m using Android Studio and I  don't like the Android  AVD. Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Check wherther you have enabled USB debugging in developer options

Comment: Yes it is enabled but the phone  just charge when connected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may write the following code in command prompt of windows

adb devices

it will give output

List of devices attached 
4200c6f0ce91a255        device

if you found your devices here it menas your device is connected via adb

If you get the error "adb is not recognized as an internal or external command. .."
Then folow these steps
just goto sdk folder in cmd and then goto platform-tools directory as in my pc its like D:\SDK\platform-tools then write adb devices

Comment: The code is not working I got a message  "adb is not recognized as an internal or external  command. .."

Comment: Oh woow that just did the the trick.  Thanks a lot. I don't know what happen after entering your command but my device suddenly got detected and as well connected in debugging mode. Can you explain please?

Comment: actually android studio automatically starts adb when you are about to run your app. but it seems that you are not using latest build tools so this causing android studio to not found adb . that's why i told you to manually start adb from cmd

Comment: Oh okay. . Thanks a lot this save me to send my phone to reparation.  My problem is solved.  Again thanks.

Comment: I'm trying but it said something like "having  15 reputation before the feed back. " I m new in the forum there any other way to vote your answer

Answer (score 0):

the same thing happened to me once and found out that the problem was with my port on phone, my phone connects as debugging when i press the wire downwards and i just connects as charging when i don't press it.

you can always go for a emulator i would recommend  genymotion first if not working go for andy or bluestacks

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I already have the AVD but I  prefer to do things with my mobile. I also tried to  press to the wire doing few adjustment but I got no detection. Any other solution please

Comment: i read below comments and saw it worked , i voted up @Umar Ata answer for u , just mark his answer as right.

Comment: I can see only "share" and "edit" potions.  There's no option to make the answer as right.  Or maybe from mobile I can't get that option or I missing it or something. ..

Comment: I also don't know how to make the problem as solved.  No option for that